# Query cache with Proxy SQL

Tags: proxysql

I'm trying to put in cache two huge queries.

With `SELECT count_star,sum_time,hostgroup,digest,digest_text FROM stats_mysql_query_digest ORDER BY sum_time DESC;` i'm able to see the digest for these two queries.

So I did:

`INSERT INTO mysql_query_rules (active,digest,cache_ttl,apply) VALUES (1,'0x82796C80785917A6',60000,1);
INSERT INTO mysql_query_rules (active,digest,cache_ttl,apply) VALUES (1,'0xC31128202A53C473',60000,1);
LOAD MYSQL QUERY RULES TO RUNTIME; SAVE MYSQL QUERY RULES TO DISK;`

but these queries are still returned from the backend and not from the query cache, as I can see by looking at column `hostgroup` returned by the 
`SELECT count_star,sum_time,hostgroup,digest,digest_text FROM stats_mysql_query_digest_reset ORDER BY sum_time DESC;`

Am I miss something ?

Comment: Query cache doesn't work with prepared statement. I've seen a reply on github.

Answer (score 0):

Query cache doesn't work with prepared statement. I've seen a reply on github.